# DateTimeFormat with Timezone and no colon

Tags: string, date, datetime, xslt, talend

I am using Talend Open Studio to fetch info from a DB to an XML file and then using XSLT on that.

There is a date field that comes into the XML as: `2013-02-13T16:49:51.733+0230`, when I supply a Date Pattern: `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"`.

I believe SimpleDateFormat has this limitation of not able to deal with colon.

I need the colon in between the timezone value: `+02:30`. How can I achieve that? Is there a different Pattern String that I can use? If not, can I do it in my XSL Transform?

Answer (score 0):

Function format-dateTime() looks for current-dateTime() format which needs colon between time zone HH:MM, in your case it is missing (0230). You should use another method to put colon between them:

```
let $x:= "2013-02-13T16:49:51.733+0230"
return concat(substring-before($x,'+'),'+',substring(substring-after($x,'+'),1,2),':',substring(substring-after($x,'+'),3,2))
```

output:

```
2013-02-13T16:49:51.733+02:30
```